# Using jQuery display 8 li at one time

Tags: jquery

its a simple one but I am not able to get it right.

I have a UL with some 80 li inside it, I want to display 8 at one time, if someone press next then next 8. I google it but still not able to find someone like it.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of jQuery [pagination modules](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination) for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$('ul > li").hide().find(":gt(0):lt(8)").show()` then on the next page click you do `$('ul > li").hide().find(":gt(8):lt(16)").show()`

Another way you can do `$('ul > li").hide().slice(0, 8).show()`